# Adding an extra property to WPF TextBox class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

I a trying to change the TextBox wpf control so that it would include an extra property (a string). Is it possible to change an existing control? Would it be possible to create a new control that inherits from TextBox?

Comment: Yes.. You can create custom controls deriving from TextBox.. you can refer my answer which i have added an extra property for decimal format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643298/wpf-custom-textbox-with-decimal-formatting/28661951#28661951

Comment: Or create an [attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add an extra property to the TextBox control. You can however inherit from the TextBox control and make your own control. Add your extra properties in your custom control.

Having said that, if you have a single property that you require, you can always use the Tag property for your custom requirements.